# Error :failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 443): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am trying to insert data into a WAMP server database. I have printed series of sequence using `System.out.print` statement to understand where the code fails. From the below mentioned code, code after executing: "Step 5" fail.

I have also tested URL in emulator's browser. It shows error as

> net::ERR CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

It seems connection is not being able to established to WAMP server.

Following is the snippet of code :

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "https://10.0.2.2/webapp/registration.php";
    String login_url = "https://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    System.out.println("Step 1");
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("register")) {
        String uname = params[1];
        String pass = params[2];
        String full_name = params[3];
        try {
            System.out.println("Step 2");
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            System.out.println("Step 3");
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("Step 4");
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            System.out.println("Step 5");
            httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("Step 6");
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("uname","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(uname,"UTF-8") +"&"+ URLEncoder.encode("pass","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8") +"&"+ URLEncoder.encode("full_name","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(full_name, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            System.out.println("Data writen");
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();
            InputStream is = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            is.close();
            return "Registration Succesful";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("URL issue");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IO Error");
        }
    }
    return null;
}`
```

Following is the statement on logcat :

```
12-17 16:44:57.582 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform I/System.out: Step 5
12-17 16:45:09.947 18840-18847/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.687ms
12-17 16:46:01.004 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 443): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
12-17 16:46:01.038 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
12-17 16:46:01.054 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
12-17 16:46:01.054 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
12-17 16:46:01.055 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
12-17 16:46:01.055 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
12-17 16:46:01.055 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
12-17 16:46:01.055 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
12-17 16:46:01.055 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
12-17 16:46:01.056 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
12-17 16:46:01.056 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
12-17 16:46:01.056 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
12-17 16:46:01.057 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
12-17 16:46:01.057 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
12-17 16:46:01.058 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:51)
12-17 16:46:01.058 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:21)
12-17 16:46:01.058 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-17 16:46:01.058 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-17 16:46:01.096 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-17 16:46:01.097 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-17 16:46:01.098 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-17 16:46:01.098 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-17 16:46:01.122 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
12-17 16:46:01.127 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
12-17 16:46:01.128 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
12-17 16:46:01.128 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
12-17 16:46:01.160 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
12-17 16:46:01.161 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/System.err:   ... 20 more
12-17 16:46:01.164 18840-18902/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform I/System.out: IO Error
12-17 16:46:01.565 18840-18847/com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.339ms
```

Solutions : ?

Comment: Do you try a simple "ping" on tablet with adb shell

Comment: Using a test php file that does not insert data, does not show any error. It seems an error is caused by a code around a write stream.

Comment: ping on tablet with adb shell works. Code is stopping at the time of creating Outstream object.

Comment: Ahhh.....Used HttpsUrlConnection instead of HttpUrlConnection class. Indeed Java is such a sensitive language